# You are given a two-digit integer n. Return the sum of its digits. Example For n = 29, the output should be addTwoDigits(n) = 11

Tags: javascript, arrays

More info:

Input/Output Details:

**[time limit]** 4000ms (js)

**[input]** integer n

A positive two-digit integer.

**Constraints**:
10 ≤ n ≤ 99.

**[output]** integer

The sum of the first and second digits of the input number.

Below is my attempt

```
function addTwoDigits(n) {

var num = n;
var n = num.toString();
var sum = n[0] + n[1];
return sum;
}

var userInput= prompt('enter a number');

if (userInput>= 10 && userInput<=99) {

return addTwoDigits(userInput);

} 

console.log(addTwoDigits(n));
```

Comment: you are adding strings...

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

`n[0]` and `n[1]` are strings. `+` is only addition for two numbers, but concatenation for any other case, so `"2" + "9"` is back at `"29"` rather than `11` that you hope for. Use `parseInt(n[0])` (and similar for `n[1]`) to turn them into something you can do arithmetic with.

Alternately, you can do this purely numerically, without ever touching strings:

```
var tens = Math.floor(n / 10);
var ones = n % 10;
var sum = tens + ones;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function addTwoDigits (input){

    var numString = input.toString()
    var numArray = numString.split('')
    var digitOne = []
    var digitTwo = []


    for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++){
      digitOne.push(numArray[0])
      digitTwo.push(numArray[1])
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < digitOne.length; i++){
      digitOne.pop()
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < digitTwo.length; i++){
      digitTwo.pop()
    }

    var numOne = parseInt(digitOne)
    var numTwo = parseInt(digitTwo)
    var sum = numOne + numTwo
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really improve the quality of your post and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you answer the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and indicate what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: it's returning 11 as expected. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer in Java.

```
int addTwoDigits(int n) {
  String number = String.valueOf(n);
  int[] nums = new int [number.length()];


  for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){
    nums[i] = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i));
  }

  return nums[0] + nums[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt`

```js
function addTwoDigits(n) {

  var num = n;
  var n = num.split("");

  var sum = parseInt(n[0]) + parseInt(n[1]);
  return sum;
}

var userInput = prompt('enter a number');

if (userInput >= 10 && userInput <= 99) {

  console.log(addTwoDigits(userInput));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addTwoDigits(n) {    
    let str = n.toString()
    if (n >= 10 && n < 100){
        return +str[0] + +str[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 1):

```
function solution(n) {
    let a = Math.floor(n/10);
    let b = n%10;
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `charAt` method and `parseInt` function to get an answer. You can see it in this code snippet:

```js
function addTwoDigits(n) {
    var string = n.toString();
    var sum = parseInt(string.charAt(0)) + parseInt(string.charAt(1));
    return sum;
}

var userInput = prompt('enter a number');

if (userInput >= 10 && userInput <= 99) {
    console.log(addTwoDigits(userInput));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addDigits(source) {
 return source
 /* convert number to string and split characters to array */
 .toString().split('')
 /* convert char[] to number[] */
 .map(function (elm) { return Number(elm); })
 /* 
    accumilate all numbers in array to value, which is initally zero. 
    REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Examples
 */
 .reduce(function (result, current) { return result + current; }, 0)
}

function validate(source) {
 if (typeof(source) == "undefined" || source == null) { throw 'value can not ne NULL ...'; }
 if ((typeof(source) !== 'number')) { throw 'value has to of NUMBER type ....'; }
 if ((source % 1)) { throw 'value has to be an INTEGER ....'; }
 if (!(source >= 10 && source <= 99)) { throw 'value is out of range 10-99 ....'; }
}

/* TESTING ......*/
var samples = [null, 'sdsad', 9.9, 9, 10, 99, 100];
samples.forEach(function (elm) {
 try {
  validate(elm);
  console.log(elm + ': ' + addDigits(elm));
 } catch (exp) {
  console.log(elm + ': ' + exp);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      var $number = $('input[name=number]'),
          $result = $('.result');
      
                                       $('input[name="calculate"]').on('click',function(){
                                     
      var total  = parseInt($number.val()),
          decens = Math.floor(total/10),
          units  = total % 10;
     if (total >9 && total < 100){
           $result.html(decens + units);
          }
          else {
            $result.html("Total must be an integer between 10 and 99");
          }
        
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <input name="number" />

    <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate"/>
                                                          
    Result:<span class="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example from me

```js
function solution(n) {
    let num = n;
    let num2 = n.toString().split("");
    let sum = parseInt(num2[0]) + parseInt(num2[1]);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Add some example if you're going to use snippet

Answer (score 0):

Follow,

```
function solution(n) {
    let num = n.toString().split('')
    return parseInt(num.reduce((acc, cur) => Number(acc) + Number(cur), 0))
}
```

```js
function solution(n) {
    let num = n.toString().split('')
    return parseInt(num.reduce((acc, cur) => Number(acc) + Number(cur), 0))
}

document.getElementById("input29").innerHTML = solution(29);

document.getElementById("input48").innerHTML = solution(48);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Example</h2>
Input 29: <p id="input29"></p>
<br>
Input 48: <p id="input48"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
function digit(x) {
  let d1=Math.floor(x/10);
  let d2=x%10;
  let sum=d1+d2;

  return sum;
}

console.log(digit(29));
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is materially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/41627691/8517948 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74102209/8517948, only with a bit less context. Please add an explanation or something to make your answer different or gain enough reputation to upvote an existing one instead.